# Using several database setups with Lucene.Net

Tags: lucene.net, indexing, nhibernate.search

Hi
I am developing a search function for an web application with Lucene.Net and NHibernate.Search. The application is used by a lots of companies but is runned as a single service, using different databases for different companies. Therefore I would need an index directory for each database rather than one directory for the entire application. Is there a way of achieve this in Lucene.Net?

I have also considering storing the indexes for each company in there respecitive database but havent found any satisfying compontents for this. I have read about Compass and JdbcDirectory for Java but I need something for C# or NHibernate. Does anyone know if there is a port of JdbcDirectory or something simular for C#?

Comment: No idea if you can get there using nhibernate search, but you could easily do this with Lucene.NET natively but it will require a bit of coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, it looks like you can't change anything at the session factory level using normal nhibernate.search.  You may need separate instances of a configuration, or maybe try something along the lines of [Fluent NHibernate Search](https://github.com/trullock/Fluent-NHibernate-Search/wiki) to ease the pain.

Piecing it together from the project's wiki it appears you could do something like this to spin up separate session factories pointing to different databases / index directories:

```
Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory())
    .Search(s => s.DefaultAnalyzer().Standard()
                             .DirectoryProvider().FSDirectory()
                             .IndexBase("~/Index")
                             .IndexingStrategy().Event()
                             .MappingClass<LibrarySearchMapping>())
    .BuildConfiguration()
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

The "IndexBase" property and the connection are the parts you'll need to define per customer.  Once you get the session factories set up you could resolve them using whatever strategy you use currently.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I simply setting up different IndexBase:es for each company/user. Seems to work really smooth

Comment: Awesome, I haven't used Fluent NHibernate search but I'm glad to hear it works well.  I love the idea of getting the field configuration out of attributes, that's been one of my main gripes with NHibernate.Search.